# Timeout for closing the position (similar to stop loss timeout)

Tags: pine-script

Please see below the script. I would like to create a timeout function for the `LongExit` variable. This will be similar to that of 3Commas' Stop Loss Timeout function (see link below):

https://help.3commas.io/en/articles/3108979-stop-loss-timeout

`LongExit` variable depends on `ta.crossunder(close, out13EMA)`. This condition will be calculated on every tick, since this is a `strategy` with `calc_on_every_tick=true`. During the bar (bar is still open, not closed yet), once `LongExit` condition is true (closing price crossunders EMA 13), this will not trigger a LongExit immediately. Instead, timeout function (in seconds) will then be effective, (for example, `timeout=input.int(defval="60", title="timeout in seconds")`, it will delay the LongExit for 60 seconds.

If LongExit condition is still valid after 60 seconds, the long position will be closed.

If LongExit condition is no longer valid (invalid) after 60 seconds, the long position will not be closed.

How is it possible to add such a timeout function?

Thank you!

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Stop Loss Timeout", shorttitle="SL Timeout", overlay=true, pyramiding=0, calc_on_every_tick=true, close_entries_rule='ANY')



//////////////////////
//////  EMA //////////
//////////////////////


//EMA 5

len5EMA = input.int(defval=5, minval=1, title="EMA 5", group="EMA")
src5EMA = input(close, title="Source EMA 5")
out5EMA = ta.ema(src5EMA, len5EMA)
plot(out5EMA, title="EMA 5", color=color.green, linewidth=2)

//EMA 13

len13EMA = input.int(defval=13, minval=1, title="EMA 13", group="EMA")
src13EMA = input(close, title="Source EMA 13")
out13EMA = ta.ema(src13EMA, len13EMA)
plot(out13EMA, title="EMA 13", color=color.red, linewidth=2)


//EMA 50

len50EMA = input.int(defval=50, minval=1, title="EMA 50", group="EMA")
src50EMA = input(close, title="Source EMA 50")
out50EMA = ta.ema(src50EMA, len50EMA)
plot(out50EMA, title="EMA 50", color=color.teal, linewidth=2)

////////////////////////////////
/// ENTRY AND EXIT CONDITIONS //
////////////////////////////////

LongEntry = ta.crossover(out5EMA, out13EMA)
LongExit = ta.crossunder(close, out13EMA)

ShortEntry = ta.crossunder(out5EMA, out13EMA)
ShortExit = ta.crossover(close, out13EMA)


// Long Entry and Long Exit with SL and TP

// Long Entry

if (strategy.position_size == 0 and strategy.closedtrades == strategy.closedtrades[1])   // Only 1 long entry per bar (similar to alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    if LongEntry
        strategy.entry(id="LE", direction=strategy.long)


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////
//// Similar to 3commas stop loss timeout
////
//// https://help.3commas.io/en/articles/3108979-stop-loss-timeout
////
//// How could I add a timeout for long exit. For example, 'LongExit' variable will be calculated on every tick. 
//// Then, once 'LongExit' becomes true (=ta.crossunder(close, out13EMA), we will wait for 60 seconds before closing the long position.
//// If after 'LongExits' becomes invalide after 60 seconds waiting time, then the long position will not be closed. 
//// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Long Exit

if LongExit
    strategy.close(id="LE")



// Short Entry and Short Exit with SL and TP


// Short Entry

if (strategy.position_size == 0 and strategy.closedtrades == strategy.closedtrades[1])   // Only 1 short entry per bar (similar to alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    if ShortEntry
        strategy.entry(id="SE", direction=strategy.short)


// Short Exit

if ShortExit
    strategy.close(id="SE")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=5
strategy("The strategy example. Close position by timeout", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, process_orders_on_close=true)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

closePositionAfter(timeoutS)=>
    if strategy.opentrades > 0
        for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades-1
            if time - strategy.opentrades.entry_time(i) >= timeoutS*1000
                entry = strategy.opentrades.entry_id(i)
                strategy.close(entry, comment = str.format("Close \"{0}\" by timeout {1}s", entry, timeoutS))
                
closePositionAfter(120) // close position after 120 sec
```

How it works you can see [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/Tqq1lFCS-The-strategy-example-Close-position-by-timeout/)